# Is there a minimum tag size on answers.ros.org?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't know if it is just me or answers.ros.org. When I search "osx" I get no returned questions. When I search "lion" I get a bunch of questions returned, most with the "osx" tag attached. Is this just me or is this a bug/feature? I also do not get anything if I search "ROS" which leads me to think a tag must be at least 4 letters long.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31517/is-there-a-minimum-tag-size-on-answers.ros.org?/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can refer to this question here:

http://answers.ros.org/question/10335/ros-answers-search-bar-broken

---

Originally posted by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) with karma: 674 on 2012-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-04-09**:
Thanks! So it is broken.

**Comment by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on 2012-04-09**:
Yea...I'm pretty sure it still is.